# Sliding background for navigation elements works only with 2 elements, not more

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a responsive page selector on my page. I'm trying to create a colored background for the currently active element. The current code works fine with 2 elements, but if I add any more, then the positioning will not work. This may be related to my lack of knowledge about the [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) jQuery function.

Here is the JavaScript code that controls the backgrounds position: (the `$.parseURL()` function just tests the URL of the page and then this code matches it to the given list element)

```
$.pageSlider = function(todo){
    if (todo === 'update'){
        $('.pageSlider a.active:not([href="'+$.parseURL().hash+'"])').removeClass('active');
        $('.pageSlider a[href="'+$.parseURL().hash+'"]').addClass('active');
        $('.pageSlider').each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            var $slideBtn = $this.find('a.slide-button');
            
            var $navs = $this.find('a[href]');
            var navsSize = $navs.size();
            var percent = 100/navsSize;
            var actNavIndx = $navs.index('a.active');

            $navs.css('width',percent+'%');
               console.log(actNavIndx);
            $slideBtn.css('width',percent+'%').animate({left:((actNavIndx*-1)*percent)+'%'});
        });
        return $('.pageSlider a.active[href="'+$.parseURL('/index.php').hash+'"]');
    }
};
window.location.hash = 'lounge';
$.pageSlider("update");
$(window).on('hashchange',function(){
    $.pageSlider("update");
});
```

2 element demo:

```js
(function($) {
  $.parseURL = function(str) {
    if (typeof str === 'undefined' && typeof window.location.href !== 'undefined') str = window.location.href;
    var check = {
        whole: /^((http|https):\/\/)?((.*\.)?.*\..*|localhost|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\/.*/,
        protocol: /^(http|https):\/\//,
        absolute: /^\/\/((.*\.)?.*\..*|localhost|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\//,
        relative: /^[\/](?!\/).*(\..*|\/)?.*$/,
        params: /\?.*=.*(\&.*\=.*)+[^#.*]/,
      },
      r = {
        protocol: undefined,
        hostname: undefined,
        hash: undefined,
        href: {
          original: undefined,
          noparams: undefined,
        },
        parentDomain: undefined,
        parameters: undefined,
        pathname: {
          nohash: undefined,
          withhash: undefined,
        },
        type: undefined,
      };
    if (typeof str !== 'string') throw new TypeError('Argument must be a string!');
    else if (!check.whole.test(str) && !check.absolute.test(str) && !check.relative.test(str)) throw new Error('Invalid string');

    r.href.original = str;

    if (str.indexOf('#') !== -1) {
      r.hash = str.substring(str.indexOf('#'));
      str = str.substring(0, str.indexOf('#'));
    }
    if (check.params.test(str)) {
      r.parameters = {};
      var urlparams = str.match(check.params)[0].substring(1).split("&");
      for (var i = 0, l = urlparams.length; i < l; i++) {
        var item = urlparams[i].split('=');
        r.parameters[item[0]] = item[1];
      }
      str = str.replace(check.params, '');
      r.href.noparams = str + (typeof r.hash !== 'undefined' ? r.hash : '');
    }
    if (check.protocol.test(str)) {
      r.protocol = str.match(check.protocol)[0];
      r.hostname = str.replace(check.protocol, '');
      r.hostname = r.hostname.substring(0, r.hostname.indexOf('/'));
      r.parentDomain = r.hostname.split('.');
      r.parentDomain.splice(0, 1);
      r.parentDomain = r.parentDomain.join('.');
      if (r.parentDomain == '') r.parentDomain = r.hostname;

      var tmp = str.replace(check.protocol, '');
      r.pathname.nohash = tmp.substring(tmp.indexOf('/'));
      tmp = undefined;

      r.type = 'normal';
    } else {
      r.protocol = window.location.href.match(check.protocol)[0];

      if (check.absolute.test(str)) { //Link starts with "//"
        var tmp = str.replace(/^\/\//, '');
        r.hostname = tmp.substring(0, tmp.indexOf('/'));
        r.pathnam.nohashe = tmp.substring(tmp.indexOf('/'));
        r.type = 'absolute';
        r.href.original = r.href.original.replace(/^\/\//g, r.protocol);
      } else if (check.relative.test(str)) {
        r.hostname = window.location.href.replace(check.protocol, '');
        r.hostname = r.hostname.substring(0, r.hostname.indexOf('/'));
        r.pathname.nohash = r.href.original;
        r.type = 'relative';
      } else {
        throw new Error('Invalid string');
      }
    }

    r.pathname.withhash = r.pathname.nohash + r.hash;

    return r;
  };

  if (typeof $('.pageSlider')[0] !== 'undefined') {
    $.pageSlider = function(todo) {
      if (todo === 'update') {
        $('.pageSlider a.active:not([href="' + $.parseURL().hash + '"])').removeClass('active');
        $('.pageSlider a[href="' + $.parseURL().hash + '"]').addClass('active');

        $('.pageSlider').each(function() {
          var $this = $(this);
          var $slideBtn = $this.find('a.slide-button');

          var $navs = $this.find('a[href]');
          var navsSize = $navs.size();
          var percent = 100 / navsSize;
          var actNavIndx = $navs.index('a.active');

          $navs.css('width', percent + '%');
          console.log(actNavIndx);
          $slideBtn.css('width', percent + '%').animate({
            left: ((actNavIndx * -1) * percent) + '%'
          });
        });

        return $('.pageSlider a.active[href="' + $.parseURL('/index.php').hash + '"]');
      }
    };
    window.location.hash = 'lounge';
    $.pageSlider("update");
    $(window).on('hashchange', function() {
      $.pageSlider("update");
    });
  }
})(jQuery);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #777;
}

@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
  .pageSlider {
    white-space: normal;
  }
  .pageSlider a[href] {
    display: block !important;
    width: 100% !important;
  }
  .pageSlider a[href].active {
    background-color: #cccc00;
  }
  .pageSlider .slide-button {
    display: none;
  }
}

.pageSlider {
  margin: 15px auto !important;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 35px;
}

.pageSlider a[href] {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.pageSlider a[href].active {
  color: #000;
}

.pageSlider .slide-button {
  background-color: #cccc00;
  position: relative;
  top: -35px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  height: inherit;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pageSlider">
  <a href="#lounge" class="active">Visitor's Lounge</a>
  <a href="#streams">News Stream</a>
  <a class="slide-button"></a>
</div>
```

vs. 3 element demo

```js
(function($){
    $.parseURL = function(str) {
        if (typeof str === 'undefined' && typeof window.location.href !== 'undefined') str = window.location.href;
        var check = {
                whole: /^((http|https):\/\/)?((.*\.)?.*\..*|localhost|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\/.*/,
                protocol: /^(http|https):\/\//,
                absolute: /^\/\/((.*\.)?.*\..*|localhost|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\//,
                relative: /^[\/](?!\/).*(\..*|\/)?.*$/,
                params: /\?.*=.*(\&.*\=.*)+[^#.*]/,
            },
            r = {
                protocol:       undefined,
                hostname:       undefined,
                hash:           undefined,
                href: {
                    original:   undefined,
                    noparams:   undefined,
                }, 
                parentDomain:   undefined,
                parameters:     undefined,
                pathname:       {
                    nohash:     undefined,
                    withhash:   undefined,
                },
                type:           undefined,
            };
        if (typeof str !== 'string') throw new TypeError('Argument must be a string!');
        else if (!check.whole.test(str) && !check.absolute.test(str) && !check.relative.test(str)) throw new Error('Invalid string');
        
        r.href.original = str;
        
        if (str.indexOf('#') !== -1){
            r.hash = str.substring(str.indexOf('#'));
            str = str.substring(0,str.indexOf('#'));
        }
        if (check.params.test(str)){
            r.parameters = {};
            var urlparams = str.match(check.params)[0].substring(1).split("&");
            for (var i=0,l=urlparams.length; i<l; i++){
                var item = urlparams[i].split('=');
                r.parameters[item[0]] = item[1];
            }
            str = str.replace(check.params,'');
            r.href.noparams = str+(typeof r.hash !== 'undefined' ? r.hash : '');
        }
        if (check.protocol.test(str)){
            r.protocol = str.match(check.protocol)[0];
            r.hostname = str.replace(check.protocol,'');
            r.hostname = r.hostname.substring(0,r.hostname.indexOf('/'));
            r.parentDomain = r.hostname.split('.');
            r.parentDomain.splice(0,1);
            r.parentDomain = r.parentDomain.join('.');
            if (r.parentDomain == '') r.parentDomain = r.hostname;
            
            var tmp = str.replace(check.protocol,'');
                r.pathname.nohash = tmp.substring(tmp.indexOf('/'));
            tmp = undefined;
            
            r.type = 'normal';
        }
        else {
            r.protocol = window.location.href.match(check.protocol)[0];
            
            if (check.absolute.test(str)){ //Link starts with "//"
                var tmp = str.replace(/^\/\//,'');
                r.hostname = tmp.substring(0,tmp.indexOf('/'));
                r.pathnam.nohashe = tmp.substring(tmp.indexOf('/'));
                r.type = 'absolute';
                r.href.original = r.href.original.replace(/^\/\//g,r.protocol);
            }
            else if (check.relative.test(str)){
                r.hostname = window.location.href.replace(check.protocol,'');
                r.hostname = r.hostname.substring(0,r.hostname.indexOf('/'));
                r.pathname.nohash = r.href.original;
                r.type = 'relative';
            }
            else {
                throw new Error('Invalid string');
            }
        }
        
        r.pathname.withhash = r.pathname.nohash+r.hash;
        
        return r;
    };
    
    if (typeof $('.pageSlider')[0] !== 'undefined'){
        $.pageSlider = function(todo){
            if (todo === 'update'){
                $('.pageSlider a.active:not([href="'+$.parseURL().hash+'"])').removeClass('active');
                $('.pageSlider a[href="'+$.parseURL().hash+'"]').addClass('active');

            $('.pageSlider').each(function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                var $slideBtn = $this.find('a.slide-button');
                
                var $navs = $this.find('a[href]');
                var navsSize = $navs.size();
                var percent = 100/navsSize;
                var actNavIndx = $navs.index('a.active');
                
                $navs.css('width',percent+'%');
                console.log(actNavIndx);
                $slideBtn.css('width',percent+'%').animate({left:((actNavIndx*-1)*percent)+'%'});
            });
                
                return $('.pageSlider a.active[href="'+$.parseURL('/index.php').hash+'"]');
            }
        };
        window.location.hash = 'lounge';
        $.pageSlider("update");
        $(window).on('hashchange',function(){
            $.pageSlider("update");
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

```css
body {
    background-color:#777;    
}

@media all and (max-width: 500px){
    .pageSlider {
        white-space: normal;
    }
    .pageSlider a[href]{
        display: block !important;
        width: 100% !important;
    }
    .pageSlider a[href].active {
        background-color: #cccc00;
    }
    .pageSlider .slide-button {
        display: none;
    }
}

.pageSlider {
    margin: 15px auto !important;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    height: 35px;
}
.pageSlider a[href] {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    
    z-index: 2;
}
.pageSlider a[href].active {
    color: #000;
}
.pageSlider .slide-button {
    background-color: #cccc00;
    position: relative;
    top: -35px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    height: inherit;

    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
        <div class="pageSlider">
            <a href="#lounge" class="active">Visitor's Lounge</a>
            <a href="#streams">News Stream</a>
            <a href="#test">Test</a>
            <a class="slide-button"></a>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed your index() is misuse :

```
var actNavIndx = $navs.index('a.active');
```

should be :

```
var actNavIndx = $this.children('a.active').index();
```

and for your animation :

```
$slideBtn.css('width',percent+'%').animate({left:((actNavIndx*-1)*percent)+'%'});
```

should be :

```
$slideBtn.css('width',percent+'%').animate({left:((actNavIndx)*percent)+'%'});
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew I was doing something wrong with `.index()`, just wasn't sure what it was.